# SQL query with multiple LIKE and NOT LIKE in WHEN statement

Tags: sql

I'm querying AWS Redshift using the script below (from my previous question) but I have troubles excluding some `referrer_url`.

For example, some of them are structured as `https://google.com/erfkhjg/facebook/sdfdfd` or `https://bing.com/erfkhjg/facebook/sdfdfd` which should be counted as `search` but are counted as `social`.

How can I exclude these links from the `social` count and count them as `search` instead? I tried to add multiple `AND ... NOT LIKE` statements in the first `SUM` block but it didn't work. Will appreciate your help!

```
SELECT A.page_id, A.views,
       SUM(CASE WHEN referrer_url LIKE '%%facebook%%' OR
                     referrer_url LIKE '%%instagram%%' OR
                     referrer_url LIKE '%%twitter%%'
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS social,
       SUM(CASE WHEN referrer_url LIKE '%%google%%' OR
                     referrer_url LIKE '%%bing%%' OR
                     referrer_url LIKE '%%yahoo%%' 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS search
FROM table1 A LEFT JOIN
     table2 B
     ON B.page_id = A.page_id   
WHERE B.dt BETWEEN '20190401' AND '20190430'
GROUP BY A.page_id, A.views;
```

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result. Move the B.dt condition to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Answer (score 0):

I think looking for a period before and after the domain name is sufficient, at least for your examples:

```
SELECT A.page_id, A.views,
       SUM(CASE WHEN referrer_url LIKE '%.facebook.%' OR
                     referrer_url LIKE '%.instagram.%' OR
                     referrer_url LIKE '%.twitter.%'
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS social,
       SUM(CASE WHEN referrer_url LIKE '%.google.%' OR
                     referrer_url LIKE '%.bing.%' OR
                     referrer_url LIKE '%.yahoo.%' 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS search
FROM table1 A LEFT JOIN
     table2 B
     ON B.page_id = A.page_id   
WHERE B.dt BETWEEN '20190401' AND '20190430'
GROUP BY A.page_id, A.views;
```

Note that you do not need two wildcards in the search pattern.

Comment: I oversimplified the example but the problem is that search results might include the exact link with social referrer patterns. E.g. https://www.link.com/?source=facebook.com/etc. and  https://google.com/sdsd/sdsd/https://www.link.com/?source=facebook.com/etc. So my condition should say - LIKE 'facebook' BUT NOT LIKE 'google'.